# Why does my contents in the first part of a breakable frame disappear?

Tags: beamer

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,t]{Exercises}
\pause
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item 
What is your name?
\begin{enumerate}[a.]
    \item Counter Terrorist
    \item Damien Walters
    \item Moderator
    \item Forgiver
    \item Higgs Boson
    \item Garbage Collector 
\end{enumerate}
\item
What is your hobby?
\begin{enumerate}[a.]
    \item Coding
    \item Reading
    \item Animating
    \item Eating
    \item Sleeping
    \item Joking
\end{enumerate}
\item
What are you doing now?
\begin{enumerate}[a.]
    \item Browsing
    \item Eating
    \item Sleeping
    \item Washing
    \item Jogging
    \item Riding
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why does my contents in the first part of a breakable frame disappear?

Comment: Because `allowframebreaks` doesn't support overlays.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: So there is no solution for this?

Comment: No, as far as I know. If you use `allowframebreaks` your overlay specifications won't work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frames with the option `allowframebreaks` don't support overlay specifications.